# Keyboard doesn't work in Ubuntu Gnome, only Ubuntu Unity

Tags: unity, keyboard, ubuntu-gnome

So to preface this, I am fairly new to Ubuntu. My plugin [Amazon Basics Gaming Keyboard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073VS6WNZ) doesn't work in Ubuntu. However, if I load up into Unity by pressing the icon next to my name on the log on screen, then my keyboard works. Why and how can I fix this?

I've looked through all the settings and my first thought was that the driver for the keyboard was missing -- it comes with a driver and software download on the Amazon webpage. I couldn't figure out how to run it; I tried Wine to run the setup.exe file, but that didn't work. I'm not very confident that this would be a fix anyhow because it works in the Unity version without the software. Only Ubuntu doesn't recognize the USB keyboard.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, I've changed your title to more accurately reflect your problem and I added a tag. But to confirm you are not using the login option titled "Wayland" correct?

Comment: No im not, its there but im not using it